# Converting video mp4 file to gif file in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ffmpeg

I am developing an web app in asp.net where I want to convert mp4 file to animated gif file. I created a sample in C# console app to test my logic where it worked smoothly but when I tried to implement the same logic in asp.net it is not working.

I am using FFmpeg.exe to convert the videos.
Here is my code that executes on Button Click. Any help would be appreciated.

```
try
{
    //srcLink = Session["videoPath"].ToString();
    System.Diagnostics.Process grabInfoProcess;
    grabInfoProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    grabInfoProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    grabInfoProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    grabInfoProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    grabInfoProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    grabInfoProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "FFmpeg\\ffmpeg.exe";
    grabInfoProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "-ss 00:00:01 -t 00:00:15" + " -i " + Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "videos\\test2.mp4" + " " + Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "DestVideos\\animated.gif";
    //ffmpeg - i source_video.avi animated_gif.gif
    grabInfoProcess.Start();
    string output = grabInfoProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    string newoutput = grabInfoProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
    grabInfoProcess.WaitForExit();

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "scriptkey", "alert('" + ex.Message.ToString() + "');");
}
```

Comment: “It is not working” is not a good description of the problem. What IS it doing? What did you try already to narrow it down?